# I would like to know how to set the time using Python in the Linux operating system

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

OS : Ubuntu LTS 18.04

Language : Python3

I am using Ubuntu Linux OS and I want to set the current time in Python language if the OS time is different from the current time. To set the Linux time, it was confirmed that the following system command was executed.

And the current time is reading information from a separate GPS device.

```
sudo date -s "2021-08-04 10:07:01"
```

In order to be able to execute this system command in Python, a test was conducted using the subprocess library.

```py
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "date", "-s", currenttime])
```

However, it does not run normally. I'm guessing it's probably because you're using the `sudo` command. So, when I ran it except for the sudo part, "You do not have permission to execute the date command." message is output.

```py
import subprocess 

proc = subprocess.Popen(["date", "-s", currenttime])
```

I don't know if I'm approaching in the wrong direction. Can you give me a wise answer?

Comment: You don't want this homebrew thing at all.  You want `chronyd` plus `gpsd` for automatic and accurate clock sync of your system to GPS.  All off the shelf and available on Ubuntu.

Comment: you need run python script with sudo,example `sudo python sync.py`

Comment: Is there any other way? There are parts that cannot be executed because the library currently being referenced has not been installed with the sudo command.

Comment: What's `currenttime`?

Comment: Can you run your python script via sudo instead?

Comment: How does it fail when you run it with `sudo`? Does your current user have `sudo` privileges?

Answer (score -2):

Import the subprocess library

`import subprocess`

Now check the output of your running cmd by storing into variable. If you want to set new data just give the whole cmd into that fn just replace the cmd from your

`output = subprocess.check_output("cmd", shell=True)`

Comment: `check_output` is definitely an improvement over `Popen` but then the `shell=True` is definitely not an improvement. Anyhow, it's not clear how you think this would solve the actual problem that the OP is asking about.